# Why does corecrt.h give me this error in VS2019?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I try to make a C program (helloworld level) in VS 2019.
Now I get an error message on corecrt.h:

```
#if ( defined _CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES && _CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES) || \
  (!defined _CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES && !__STDC__                 )   <====== here
  #define _CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES 1
#else
  #define _CRT_INTERNAL_NONSTDC_NAMES 0
#endif
```

litterally copy/paste!

That's a weird line, with these duplicates in it.
The message (invalid integer constant expression) occurs on the line with the lots-of-spaces and a ")" (arrow is mine)

1: what is so wrong about the line?

2: why do I need this core thing at all, for just a straight C helloworld program?

3: there is a lot of "core" in the external dependencies. Why?

Comment: Who tells you that you *do* need it for a "Hello, World!" program? The reason for the duplicate use, is that `_CRT_DECLARE_NONSTDC_NAMES` is being used in different ways. First if it is defined, then its value, then if it is *not* defined, and some other value.

Comment: when I set up the project and add a main.c,  the core stuff gets included automatically in the ext. deps